# Keyboard layout change indicator

Tags: x11, keyboard-layout, xkb, notifications

I have (and often change) 3 keyboard layouts on my Mint 17/Mate. I would like to see a notification on my screen when layout is changed, e.g. "Switched to English/US". I tried to do it via keyboard settings, to find a program or script to do it, but I couldn't.

The question is: are there any programs to show current layout OR is there a way to catch layout change event from X11 in user script? Any advice or guide to information would be appreciated.

Update: I've found `notify-send` to actually send notification, now I need to catch layout change event.

Comment: How do you switch between layouts? If it's with XKB, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15499723/which-event-is-fired-when-switching-kb-layout-in-x-org . I don't know what ready-made programs react to that event.

Comment: @Gilles Thanks for reference, need to check full event processing loop in X11 / GTK, but it is still helpful and still better than nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't change my keyboard layout very often, but when i do it, i use (for exemple) :

```
setxkbmap fr
```

There's also an option to show the current layout of your keyboard :

```
setxkbmap -query
```

result :

```
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     fr
options:    terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp
```

Considering this, you could do something with the notify-send command to send the layout as a notification. Something like this :

```
notify-send $(setxkbmap -query | grep layout)
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I hoped there is a way to catch the layout change, but looks like i'll have to stick to catching layout change key press and work with it.